# Changing FPS on zoom video in Linux

Tags: linux, video, webcam, zoom-meeting

I have bought a new Logitech C920 HD Pro Webcam and when running it the florescent strobe lights in the room cause a flickering in the video.

**I can fix this by changing the fps of the webcam to 20fps** using `guvcview -d /dev/video1` where `/dev/video1` is the newly plugged in camera and not my built in laptop webcam.

This tool is great for making the changes and seeing the effects live on the video. 24fps creates some flickering and 30fps make it quite bad. Changing this to 20fps with this tool saves it (or so it appears to save as when i re open it it has my changes already set).

Zoom however has very limited video settings options and appears to be overwriting these settings as the flickering matches the 30fps I see in `guvcview`.

Is there anyway to enforce Zoom to use these settings OR alter it as my new webcam quality is great but unusable due to the intense flickering?

Comment: You might be able to do this with `V4L2Loopback` which creates a "fake" webcam device; https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/528400/how-can-i-stream-my-desktop-screen-to-dev-video1-as-a-fake-webcam-on-linux for example or Google around using v4l2loopback name.

Comment: Thanks but the fake webcam solution seems to use X11 (your screen) and treat that as a webcam which is different to what I'm after. I want the webcam settings to stick on Zoom. I can make the changes in `/dev/video1` fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in the UK/Europe, to stop flickering you need to set the powerline frequency to 50Hz.

First install v4l-utils

```
sudo apt-get install v4l-utils
```

Then use the command below

```
v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl=power_line_frequency=1
```

I have added that to my startup with a 10s delay to make sure the webcam is up and running first, problem solved.